# SignalR notifying both asp.net and web api clients host on separate site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr, notify

I'm going to build my own system include asp.net web site and web api, they are host on separate site. Architect diagram like image link below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAlCO.jpg]

Every time client update something. I need to notify to the others. For example if client 1 upload a photo via web, then client 3 and (mobile app) and client 4(desktop app) should get a notification.
My problem is how to tell SignalR send notify to clients in this case. Please advice.

Comment: Diagram looks nice but still a bit confusing, can you provide more info about ASP.NET node? I would expect that in your design you would have ASP.NET MVC which just consumes Web Api by some MVVM framework (e.g Knockoutjs).

Comment: Hi van i am working on the application having the same requirements. Did you completed this one? I have no idea how i can do this. Is signalR is compatible for IOS also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagram must be changed in order to achieve what you need.

In order for this to work all the client types must be SignalR aware. For the web application it's straightforward since the "client" code is the website code itself.

For the mobile and desktop you have an extra layer (webapi) which in this case is an obstacle.

You should define a SignalR hub and connect to it from all the clients: WebApp, MobileApp, DesktopApp.

Knowing this, you can make a WebAPI project containing all the API methods and the SignalR hub(s) and connect to it from the other applications, website included.

As far as I know this is the only way to make this work, as you need to include SignalR library in all the clients code and use it to communicate with the hub(s).